# Random vectors of changing length

Tags: probability-theory

Let

- $\mathbb{S}$ be a standard Borel space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$)
- $X=(X_n):\mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N}$ be the coordinate map, i.e., $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$ where $\omega = (\omega_1,\omega_2,...)\in \mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N}$
- $\theta:\mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N}$ be the shift operator defined by $(\theta \omega)_n = \omega_{n+1}$
- $T$ be a stopping time with respect to the filtration $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ and let
- $T_n = T_{n-1} + T \circ \theta^{T_{n-1}}$ with $T_0 = 0$

In Durrett, Theorem 4.14 states that

> Suppose $P(T<\infty)=1$. Then the "random vectors" 
>   $$V_n = (T\circ \theta^{T_{n-1}}, X_{T_{n-1}+1},...,X_{T_n})$$
>   are iid (independent and identically distributed)

Usually, when defining independence, we just need to prove 
$$P(X\in A,Y\in B) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$$
The problem here is that the vector $V_n$ has different lengths for different values of $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^\mathbb{N}$, so I'm not completely sure what kind of space should sets $A$ and $B$ be in.

Comment: Each $V_n$ is a random variable with values in $$\bigcup_{k\geqslant1}\left(\{k\}\times\mathbb S^k\right)$$

Comment: @Did I realize that $V_n$ lies in the space you showed, but what kind of Borel $\sigma$-algebra does your space have? And more importantly, its relation to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{S}$?

Comment: Borel sets are $$B=\bigcup_{k\geqslant1}\left(\{k\}\times B_k\right)$$ where each $B_k$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb S^k$.